# How to remove the backdrop of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox

Quick Question. In the image link below you should be able to see a window and in it a `JComboBox`. Behind the combo box is a backdrop of light grey, but the color of the `JPanel` is Dark Gray. How do I make this backdrop transparent? In other words, how to I remove the light grey of the combo box?

[image]

Comment: Wait, what color, do you want the combo box background? The color or the dark gray panel or white?

Comment: What is combobox sitting in?

Comment: @MadProgrammer
The combo box is on top of a large Jpanel

Comment: Kevin Workman's solution worked. Thanks, I thought it would be a quick fix.

Comment: And that's sitting I you darker panel?

Answer (score 3):

You first stop for questions like these should be the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

```
JComboBox.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Can you provide any more information other than "it doesn't work"? Is your JComboBox inside another JPanel? Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem with just a simple JFrame and JComboBox displaying?

Comment: @KevinWorkman this worked. Thank you, I thought it would be something as easy as this. This is why I didnt provide code. :)

Comment: +1 for solving the OP problem. For some reason it didnt work when testing it with a JOptionPane

Comment: Sorry, my request for an SSCCE was in response to peeskillet's original comment saying "it didn't work". Obviously this won't work on a JOptionPane, since this is code for a JComboBox. :)